# Failing hard drive. How to find out which one?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a "failing" hard drive that makes some noise once in a while(*15 min or so*).sound ex: [search for: Samsung 40GB desktop hard drive with bad head knocks a few times.](http://datacent.com/failing_hard_drive_sounds)

I have used "*Seatools*" and "*Hard disk sentinel*" to diagnose the problem and monitor S.M.A.R.T, but all the tests passes and everything runs fine.

The problem is that I have lots of hard drives in my computer(complex raid configuration) and I want to find out which one makes the sound to replace it. I can not reproduce the sound on demand myself and its really hard to listen which of the hard drive makes that sound.

How can i diagnose and find out which of the hard disk is the "failing" one?

**UPDATE:**

OS: Windows 10(*sadly*)

Results by `wmic`:

```
Status
OK
OK
OK
...
```

Comment: Keep something like a piece of wooden dowel handy (if you don't have one, use a large screw driver and be careful), and leave the case open for access to the drives.  While the noise is happening, use the dowel like a stethoscope--one end on a drive, the other against your ear.  Try it with each drive to identify the culprit.  Note that the noise might not be coming from a drive, fans are a common source of similar noises.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make a backup! (*RAID is not a backup).

You don't say what O/S you're using so my answer will be very generic, if/when you update the question you'll likely get something more specific

Check both the O/S monitoring and SMART monitoring which comes on SSD/HDD as standard.

On linux you'd likely use `smartctl` and want to run both the short and long tests; as well as this you can check for any error messages in dmesg - it should show if any of your interfaces are failing.

On windows you'd use

`wmic
diskdrive get status`

to get the status of SMART on the drives,
To run the tests on windows seems to require 3rd party tools and I have no experience with them to suggest one. (You could use smartctl from a live linux cd tho!). Also you might find errors listed in the windows logs accessed via the control panel.

Comment: So my answer about having to use a 3rd party tool still stands now you've confirmed you're using windows, however you might want to try a live linux CD anyway.

Comment: Great answer, but maybe i wasn't clear, i have tried 3rd party tools like "Seatools" and "Hard disk sentinel".  I ran both the short and long and all tests passes.